# Next-Auth signIn with google Issue

Tags: reactjs, google-signin, next.js13, next-auth, react-fullstack

I'm new to the next.js 13 and I've been learning since a month and when I'm trying to integrate the sign in with google  with next-auth in my next.js project I was getting errors.

I've tried using app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts and I was getting 404 error.

So tried to access the sign with google using signIn from next-auth/react, and when the button is clicked then I was getting this error "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/error"